# vim indentation in C++ constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, vim

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Example
{
    public:
        Example(int a,int b,int c):m_a(a),m_b(b),m_c(c)
    {  // Wrong indentation here due to the colon in above line, { should be under E
        printf("\nThe 3 argument constructor invoked\n");
    } // Wrong indentation again
    private:
        int m_a;
        int m_b;
        int m_c;
};
```

Hi all,

I have a little problem in gvim's indentation in the constructor initialization list in C++.
I am using cindent in the .gvimrc and i am unable to solve this problem even after changing my .gvimrc a number of times.

Can some benevolent soul give me some method to set this up. I have tried changing cinoptions as well as cinwords but nothing really helped.

I have highlighted the indentation problem in the code snippet provided above.

Thanks for your patience

Regards
lali

Comment: check this out as well http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=493776

Comment: I see same problem with EMACS.

Answer (score 2):

```
:set cino=i0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `:set smartindent`, I had to disable cindent first to get it working.

Comment: No this doesn't solve the problem. Setting smartindent after disabling cindent only solves this problem, but i want cindent as well for future indentation which is not available if cindent is disabled. I have already tried this solution, thanks anyway, but i want something better.

Comment: The `smartindent` help page also recommends using `autoindent`, maybe try using both of those together instead of cindent.

Answer (score 1):

I have also read and re-read the vim manual at

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values

This is quite a challenging problem. The closest I could get was using

`:set cino=g3,h3,i0`

That is, indent scope declarations (private, public, etc) by 3, indent 3 spaces after scope declaration, and don't indent constructor further.

Which resulted in

```
#include
using namespace std;
class Example
{
   public:
      Example(int a,int b,int c):m_a(a),m_b(b),m_c(c)
      {  // Wrong indentation here due to the colon in above line, { should be under E
         printf("\nThe 3 argument constructor invoked\n");
      } // Wrong indentation again
```

```
     private:
  int m_a;
  int m_b;
  int m_c;

  };
```

This isn't quite what you wanted but experimenting with g,h,i can get pretty close.

Please comment if this helps or if I have sparked any ideas. Perhaps the bug report is the best way to get this issue resolved. Though a workaround is to override cindent by manual edits, as inglorious as that is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option, but you could have a look at [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).  We use TextMate at work, and the (default?) indentation scheme is not what we want some of the time.  But mostly it follows the indentation of the previous line after pressing enter or something.

The solution we use is simply piping the full source of the file through astyle (using appropriate options), and this is bound to a shortcut key.  This is afaik also possible with vim.