# How do I fix indentation in Vim after multiline c++ initialization list?

Tags: c++, vim, indentation

In Vim, when I have a long constructor that forces me to put initialization list items on separate lines, my indentations look like this after autoformatting with something like `gg=G`.

```
Really_Long_Class_Name::Really_Long_Class_Name(int _arg1, int _arg2) :
  arg1(_arg1),
  arg2(_arg2) {
    do_stuff();
  }
```

I want it to be indented like this:

```
Really_Long_Class_Name::Really_Long_Class_Name(int _arg1, int _arg2) :
    arg1(_arg1),
    arg2(_arg2) {
  do_stuff();
}
```

After looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2288678/2680824), I got closer by playing around with `cinoptions`. By using `:set cino+=i4,e-4,0}-4` I got it to look the way I want, but then my alignment is screwed up if all the initialization list items are on the same line, like so:

```
Other_Class::Other_Class(int _arg1, int _arg2) : arg1(_arg1), arg2(_arg2) {
do_stuff();
}
```

How can I fix indentation for this one case without throwing off indentation for other cases?